# SAS libname odbc, how to access a two-level name table

Tags: odbc, sas

I recently found the libname statement is very handy to access tables reside in odbc. But I don't know how to access those tables having a two-level names. Below is an example.

Old code I use (this code works):

```
proc sql;
    connect to odbc(dsn=edw_nz user=&username. pw=&password.);

    create table test select * from connection to odbc(
        select  *
        from EDW_XYZ_PROD01..Table_xyz);
quit;
```

Now, I want to use the libname facility to access the odbc:

```
libname edw odbc database=edw_nz user=&username. pw=&password.;
proc sql;
    create table test as
        select *
        from edw.EDW_XYZ_PROD01..Table_xyz;
quit;
```

I got this error: 
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, (, ), ',', ANSIMISS, AS, CROSS, EXCEPT, FULL, GROUP, HAVING, INNER, INTERSECT, JOIN, LEFT, NATURAL, NOMISS, OUTER, RIGHT, UNION, WHERE.
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

Any one can help?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SAS cannot handle 3 level names.

You need to specify the schema/database inside the libname section.  You have a few options (read the doc for all the options).

We use ODBC to connect to our SQL server instances like this:

```
libname pdata odbc complete='DSN=SQLServerProd;Database=MyDatabase';
```

The `complete=` option allows you specify the full ODBC connection string.  This should allow you to specify the database/schema.

Answer (score 2):

Is EDW_XYZ_PROD01 a schema or something?

I think you might have to specify that on the datasource= option.  For example:

```
libname mydblib odbc user=testuser password=testpass datasrc=mydatasource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the schema= option on the libname statement. The schema is equivalent to the first level name.

```
libname edw odbc database=edw_nz user=&username. pw=&password. schema=edw;

proc sql;
  create table test as
    select *
    from EDW_XYZ_PROD01..Table_xyz;
quit;
```